# C# - Task Exception not being caught

Tags: c#

I am sure I am doinig something wrong, but when I try this example of the new threading task exception handling I keep getting the exception unhandled by user code.  The whole point of the code is to show an example of how to catch errors in tasks.

Link: [Task Exception Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                throw new MyCustomException("I'm bad, but not too bad!");
            });

            try
            {
                task1.Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                // Assume we know what's going on with this particular exception. 
                // Rethrow anything else. AggregateException.Handle provides 
                // another way to express this. See later example. 
                foreach (var e in ae.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    if (e is MyCustomException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Most likely user error just not sure what (Using Visual Studio 2012);

Comment: Scroll to "Note" in the big yellow box. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the page you cited:

> **Note**
>
> When "Just My Code" is enabled, Visual Studio in some cases will
>   break on the line that throws the exception and display an error
>   message that says "exception not handled by user code." This error is
>   benign. You can press F5 to continue and see the exception-handling
>   behavior that is demonstrated in these examples. To prevent Visual
>   Studio from breaking on the first error, just uncheck the "Just My
>   Code" checkbox under **Tools, Options, Debugging, General**.