# Exception handling outside of Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Just noticed strange thing: to catch exception in caller from new Task, lambda MUST be marked as async!? Is it really necessary even if delegate has no await operators at all?

```
    try
    {
        //Task.Run(() =>      // exception is not caught!
        Task.Run(async () =>  // unnecessary async!?!   
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception in Task");
        }).Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        res = ex.Message;
    }
```

Why there is neccesary for async operator? 
All documentation i can find tells that delegate must not return Void and Task must be awaited for exception to propogate up to caller.

Added full code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.Run();
    }

public void Run()
{
    string result;

    try
    {
        result = OnSomeEvent((s, ea) => RunSomeTask());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // Try to catch unhandled exceptions here!
    {
        result = ex.Message;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

// Some other Framework bult-in event (can not change signature)
public string OnSomeEvent(EventHandler e)
{
    e.Invoke(null, new EventArgs());
    return "OK";
}

private async Task RunSomeTask()
{
    await Task.Run(async () => // do not need async here!!!
    //await Task.Run(() =>     // caller do not catches exceptions (but must)
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception in Task1");
    });
}
}
```

So the qestion is how to catche ex. without asyn keyword???

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `async` - I suspect throwing an exception breaks the delegate type inference. Try specifying the delegate type explictly.

Comment: You say *exception is not caught!* when async isn't used. But indeed it is caught. Is this your actual code?

Comment: @Lee is correct. I remember reading a duplicate on this exact topic a few months ago. Throwing  a exception changes the return type of the anonymous delegate.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, updated actual code.

Comment: What happens in both the cases? What do you mean by works? Instead of saying works, can you tell what behavior you're observing in both the cases?

Comment: If throwing is the *only* way out of the lambda passed to `Task.Run`, the [lambda is indeed inferred](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24359762/1768303) as `Func<Task>` rather than `Action`. But the exception in the your first code fragment still does get caught.

Comment: arghh... if only someone pointed me to this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022162/c-sharp-task-exception-not-being-caught
:)

Answer (score 1):

Methods that return `Task` - such as `Task.Run` or `async` methods - will place any exceptions on that returned `Task`. It's up to you to observe that exception somehow. Normally this is done with `await`, like this:

```
await Task.Run(() => { throw ... });
```

In your case, the problem is in this line:

```
result = OnSomeEvent((s, ea) => RunSomeTask());
```

In this code, `RunSomeTask` is returning a `Task`, and that `Task` is never awaited. In order to observe the exception, you should `await` that task.

Comment: where did you suggest to put this 'await' operator? Becouse edit it this way `result = OnSomeEvent(async (s, ea) => await RunSomeTask());` do not catch ex. either, it becames lambda what returns 'void'.

Comment: @Arvis: You have to rethink your solution. What you're trying to do right now is sync-over-async, a well-known anti-pattern. You'll have to either make your code fully asynchronous, or save the task somewhere and react to it at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

When using `async`/`await`, exceptions are automatically unwrapped at the site of the `await`. When using a `Task` and `.Wait()`, any exception are wrapped when they come out of the `Task`, and thus getting information requires you to dig into the [`Task.Exception`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, since they do not propagate up the call stack.

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/MmEXsT

Comment: In particular case it no matter what i use 'wait' or 'await'. I tested both.

Comment: Totally forgot it was in a property - updated my anser thusly